# Using FindMinimum to solve equations as constraints

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

As suggested [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/797087), a system of equations can be seen as constraints in a minimization procedure with a zero cost function.

For instance:

```
f[x_, y_] := {x + 3 y^3, Sin[x^2 - y + 1]}
FindRoot[f[x, y], {{x, -1}, {y, -1}}]
(* {x -> -1.72425, y -> 0.831431} *)

FindMinimum[{0, Thread[f[x, y] == 0]}, {x, y}]
(* {0., {x -> -1.72425, y -> 0.831431}} *)
```

**Questions**

1. How does `FindMinimum` work in that case?
2. Are there cases where this approach would be more efficient that `FindRoot`?

Comment: `FindMinimum[]` just uses an [interior point algorithm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html#442312913) in the constrained case.