# Why Wolfram|Alpha can solve an equation but not Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to numerically solve $$\cosh\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{x^2}\sinh\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0.$$

A strange thing is that Wolfram|Alpha it solves it perfectly, but Mathematica I have this:

[image]

How can this be possible?

Comment: what is the output from Wolfram?

Comment: Please post the input you gave to Wolfram alpha language also. The Wolfram alpha is different from the Wolfram Mathematica language. You could have typed something which Wolfram alpha understood to be something different from Wolfram mathematica, since Wolfram alpha is AI based and uses natural language input which is not the case with the Wolfram Mathematica language.

Comment: Use FindRoot[Cosh[1/x] - 1/x^2 Sinh[1/x], {x, 1}]

Comment: @Nasser - this is the OP's input: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=solve+cosh(1%2Fx)+-1%2Fx%5E2+sinh(1%2Fx)+%3D%3D+0

Comment: `NSolve` requires some domain restrictions so that there will be finitely many solutions. `In[124]:= NSolve[
 Cosh[1/x] - Sinh[1/x]/x^2 == 0 && 0 < x < 100, x, Reals]

Out[124]= {{x -> 0.897517}}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau you’re correct. This is call Wolfram|Alpha uses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually NSolve is preferable for polynomical functions.
You can solve your problems in this way:

```
FindRoot[Cosh[1/x] - Sinh[1/x]/x^2, {x, .1}] (* with startvalue *)
(* {x -> 0.897517} *)
```

or

```
NMinimize[{1, Cosh[1/x] - Sinh[1/x]/x^2 == 0}, x] (* without startvalue *)
(* {1., {x -> 0.897517}} *)
```

Comment: I did not know the f[x]==0 constraint + nminimize trick... is it yours?

Comment: @Picaud Vincent: Unfortunately not ( ;-) ). I found it by chance someware in the advanced NMinimze documentation...

Comment: @PicaudVincent Related to this trick: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159589/using-findminimum-to-solve-equations-as-constraints.

Comment: @anderstood thanks

Comment: The NMinimize-trick can be found in the help NMinimize\NeatEaxamples!